# get map with id and response body from multiple requests

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

Good morning,

I have a rest api. There i can fetch the name from a given id:

```
@GET("warehouse/{wid}/name")
Observable<Response<String>> getWarehouseName(@Path(WAREHOUSE_ID) String wid);
```

I have implement this method do get the name in my client:

```
protected Observable<String> getNameObservable(final String wid) {
if (wid == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("wid is null");
}
return warehousesService.getWarehouseName(wid).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .flatMap(response -> {
            try {
                CommonResponseChecks.checkResponse(response);
                return Observable.just(response.body());
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        });
}
```

Now i want to implement a method with rxjava that get list of ids as parameter and returning a map `public Map<String, String> getNames(Collection<String> wids)`
I have these method to get a list of names:

```
public Maybe<List<String>> getNames(Collection<String> warehouseIds) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(warehouseIds).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .flatMapMaybe(wid -> getName(wid)).toList().toMaybe();
}
```

But how to convert it to the map?

sorry for my bad english ;)

best regards

Comment: In a map you have keys and values. But your input offers only one thing - the ids. So what in your map will be the key and what will be the value?

Comment: i want to connect the `wid` with the `getName(wid)` result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like that:

```
public Map<String, String> getNames(Collection<String> wids) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(warehouseIds)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(wid-> wid, wid -> getName(wid)));
}
```

Comment: I have tried it for days now. But I do not get it running. Do you have a working example for me? The example does not work. `Collectors#toMap` looks like java8 not rxjava.

Comment: Yes, it is Java8 - which jave version do you use? What version of rxjava do you use and how to install it - via maven dependency?

Comment: My java version is 8 (later maybe 7 (android)). But for streaming i use rxjava in combination with retrofit2. The version is 2.1.4 with gradle (maven dependency)

Comment: I'm sorry - I am currently totally busy and I've no time left to get to know rxjava and try something out there.